# In a multi-tenant database architecture, "control files" can't be modified by pluggable database administrator, why?

Tags: database, oracle

In a multi-tenant database architecture, "control files" can't be modified by the pluggable database administrator, why?

Answer (score 0):

There is one common control file in an Oracle multi-tenant database architecture which contains information of all the pdb's. Once you enter as a pdb DBA, you don't have the privilege to modify any parameter with respect to it. Only a DBA who has privileges to operate the container database (CDB) can modify the control file.